# Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

В `Firestore` есть коллекция user, у каждого user есть значение 'group' ： A или B.  Можно ли использовать значение 'group' как фильтр, получая всех users группы А и В.

Answer (score 0):

```
          ----------------------------------------------------------
          |           -------------------------------------------  |
          | User1 --> | [group:{...}, group:{...}, group:{...}] |  |
Users --> | User2 --> | [group:{...}, group:{...}, group:{...}] |  |
          | User3 --> | [group:{...}, group:{...}, group:{...}] |  |
          |           -------------------------------------------  |
          ----------------------------------------------------------
```

[Получить все под-коллекции, если у них одинаковые имена](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('group').getDocuments()
```